# how to get a dependency graph of all sbt plugins brought in transitively into one's project?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using sbt-dependency-graph to understand the chain of *libraryDependencies* pulled in by my application, and i would like to find a solution for understanding the dependencies pulled in (transitively) by the sbt plugins I am using in my sbt project.   To further clarify... the focus here is understanding the  dependencies of the sbt plugins I am using, not the dependencies of the application itself.   Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

Since the question was asked, 7 years ago, the dependency tree plugin has been merged into `sbt` and the `dependencyTree` task is automatically available to all projects.

Based on this old github issue https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph/issues/66 I was able to come up with a solution for `sbt` 1.8.2 on how to list a project's plugins' dependencies.

1. Start a sbt shell by running `sbt`
2. Run the task `reload plugins`
3. Run the task `dependencyTree` to see the plugins' dependencies

According to https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Commands+for+managing+the+build+definition `reload plugins` changes the current project to the build definition project which I guess is what causes dependencyTree to display the plugins' dependencies instead of the normal library dependencies. Run `reload return` to get back to the normal project.

If you want to have access to the other dependency tasks such as dependencyBrowseGraph you need to create the file `project/project/plugins.sbt` with the contents `addDependencyTreePlugin`.

Comment: thanks .. yes. i use dependencyTree alot ;^)

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer and should probably be accepted. I think that the fact that it uses `dependencyTree` might have given you the wrong impression that this answer was also just pointing to that. The additional guidance and link to the documentation helped me find a problem with conflicting transitive dependency across plugins. Thanks @gabrielf!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the command `dependencyBrowseGraph`? I believe it shows a graphical view of the dependency tree.

Other options can be found in the documentation of the project's GitHub repository: https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph

Comment: Thanks I use this plugin and love it.     But it doesn't work for the use case I mentioned (unless you know of some switch that will do the trick... which i certainly don't know).

Comment: Why doesn't it work for your case? You just need to add it to your project's project (meta-project), i.e. `project/project/plugins.sbt` and then switch to the meta-project in sbt with `reload plugins` command. Then use `dependencyBrowseGraph` or other commands from the plugin.

Comment: Thanks..  this will give me an opportunity to learn the recursive aspect of .sbt (which they call turtles all the way down for some reason.)  I will try this with a very simple project that uses an .sbt plugin that has a dependency on another plugin, and if i succeed will publish the results.

Comment: @ChrisBedford check wikipedia about ["turtles all the way down"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).